# How to downgrade a Visual Studio extension?

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vs-extensibility

I need to downgrade [NuGet Package Manager extension for Visual Studio 2015](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5d345edc-2e2d-4a9c-b73b-d53956dc458d) for testing purpose. How to do this? Is there any way to download an older version of this extension and install it into Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This site lists all recent releases, you must install the VSIX file.
https://github.com/NuGet/Home/releases

Comment: Yes, its available. But what about the other extensions which are available in VSGallery? How to downgrade those VSIX packages?

Comment: Do you mean a specific extension?

Comment: Yes. Any one of the extension available in VSGallery.

Comment: This depends on wether the vendors or publishers published their recent versions or not. In general you'll find some version log or version information on the website of the extension.

Answer (score 1):

You can usually try a variation of the link you can get from the download button from the extension's page on https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/ .

For example, at the time of this writing Failwyn/WebCompiler64 version 1.14.9.2 has an issue, so I downloaded version 1.14.8 from https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery/publishers/Failwyn/vsextensions/WebCompiler64/1.14.8/vspackage .

Answer (score -2):

An easier way to downgrade any visual studio code extension is by:

```
    1. search for the extension in visual studio code
    2. Right click on the extension you want to downgrade
    3. select Install Another Version... 
    4. Pick the version from the list if any and install
```

[VS Code - how to rollback extension/install specific extension version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42626065/vs-code-how-to-rollback-extension-install-specific-extension-version)

Comment: Question is about Visual Studio, not Visual Studio Code.