# How to stop a single VS Code extension from auto update?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Some of my vs code extension update every day, and I have a limited amount of internet bandwidth, is it possible to stop a specific extension from the auto update?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it is possible (and simple):

In the **package.json** of the extension,
you will find a **metadata section** that look like so:

```
"__metadata": {
    "id": "0fcefdee-e09c-4b96-9998-f5dc891893dd",
    "publisherId": "1e02cadf-73ee-47be-8772-75da47b7921f",
    "publisherDisplayName": "Robert Plant"
}
```

**Rename the id field**, as "**OLD id**".

Below the OLD id line, **add the following line**

```
"id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
```

You will end up with:

```
"__metadata": {
     "OLD id": "0fcefdee-e09c-4b96-9998-f5dc891893dd",
     "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
     "publisherId": "1e02cadf-73ee-47be-8772-75da47b7921f",
     "publisherDisplayName": "Robert Plant"
}
```

You **might** have to **reload** the window and/or to **disable/reenable** the extension.

**NB:** If you need to do it **for more than one extension**, you will need to **give each one a different id**, otherwise, it won't work:

```
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002
Etc.
```

That's it!

Comment: [Vscode doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace#_where-are-extensions-installed) on where extensions are installed based on the OS.

Comment: I tried this and it did not work for me, see details: https://github.com/idahogurl/vs-code-prettier-eslint/issues/41#issuecomment-1379413964

Comment: there is a file called extensions.json in the extensions  folder, it worked when i made the same changes in this file, follow the same steps that Axel explained

Answer (score 6):

So far, there are only settings for controlling all of your extensions. You can use the [settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) below:

```
{
  "extensions.autoCheckUpdates": false,
  "extensions.autoUpdate": false
}
```

Of course, you can always [submit a feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new?template=feature_request.md) for controlling specific extensions individually.

Comment: tabnine seems to ignore this.

Answer (score 0):

Update as of vscode v1.85:

> You can now choose which extensions to auto update. This is helpful if
> you do not want to auto update all extensions but selectively choose
> which ones to auto update. You can either select an extension or all
> extensions from a publisher to auto update. You can also choose to
> auto update all extensions from a publisher and then unselect
> individual extensions from that publisher.

First, enable update selected extensions:

[image: auto update selected extensions]

Then, for each extension you can do this:

[image: auto update a specific extension]

---

Previously (this method still works after vscode v1.85):

From [GH Issue: Please make it possible to disable auto-update for a specific extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/166896)

> Please try the feature `Install Another Version...` - right click on
> extension to see this action. Installing another version will lock the
> extension to that version.

So specifically choosing a certain version should stop future updates.

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53755378/836330 about pinning/reverting to a specific extension version which should not allow auto-updating.

Answer (score 0):

Add line bellow to `settings.json`

---

Use this format -
`"settingsSync.ignoredExtensions": ["extension-name"]`

You can find the name of your extensions in VS Code settings or on the marketplace.

Example for **quokka** - [VS Code extension marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WallabyJs.quokka-vscode#:%7E:text=js%20Visual%20Studio%20Code%20Extension,for%20rapid%20JavaScript%20%2F%20TypeScript%20prototyping.)

Example for **quokka** - `"settingsSync.ignoredExtensions": ["wallabyjs.quokka-vscode"]`

---

These settings will exclude extensions from auto-update.