# downloading older VSCode extension (Debugger for Java)

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Since microsoft broke the `Debugger for Java` vscode extension again I want to downgrade to an older version.

The id is `vscjava.vscode-java-debug` as can be seen in the top right corner:

[image]
vscjava.vscode-java-debug

When searching with that as id I do get the debugger:
[image]

But as I said I need the older version.

To download an older vsix this is the format:

`https://${publisher}.gallery.vsassets.io/_apis/public/gallery/publisher/${publisher}/extension/${extension_name}/${version}/assetbyname/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VSIXPackage`

Here a working example:

`https://ms-vscode.gallery.vsassets.io/_apis/public/gallery/publisher/ms-vscode/extension/csharp/1.7.0/assetbyname/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VSIXPackage`

So in the `Debugger for Java` case it should be:

`https://ms-vscode.gallery.vsassets.io/_apis/public/gallery/publisher/ms-vscode/extension/vscjava.vscode-java-debug/0.12.0/assetbyname/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VSIXPackage`

But let's not forget we are dealing with Microsoft here!

`{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"The extension ID 'vscjava.vscode-java-debug' is invalid. Extension ID must be less than 63 characters and can only contain 'A' through 'Z', 'a' through 'z', '0' through '9', and '-'. It must start with an alphanumeric character.","typeName":"System.ArgumentException, mscorlib","typeKey":"ArgumentException","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}`

I tried to get around that with trial and error changing the id, but no luck.

So does someone know how to get the older VSIX for this vscode extension?

@Mark please read the thing before you mark it as a duplicate.
Also the answer you gave in the possible duplicate was not a valid answer back in the time this question was asked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vs code - rollback extension/install specific extension version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42626065/vs-code-rollback-extension-install-specific-extension-version)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

https://ms-vscode.gallery.vsassets.io/_apis/public/gallery/publisher/vscjava/extension/vscode-java-debug/0.12.0/assetbyname/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VSIXPackage

Then rename `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VSIXPackage.zip` to `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VSIXPackage.vsix`.
That way you can use `Extensions: install from VSIX...` from within VSCode.

The scheme is:

```
https://ms-vscode.gallery.vsassets.io/_apis/public/gallery/publisher/$PUBLISHER_ID/extension/$EXT_ID/$VERSION/assetbyname/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VSIXPackage
```

For that extension:

- `PUBLISHER_ID` - vscjava
- `EXT_ID` - vscode-java-debug
- `VERSION` - 0.12.0

(None of this is official and it could break in the future)