# Visual Studio Code quick-fix & python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code is never able to populate the 'Quick Fix' contextual drop down, only displaying 'No Code Actions Available'

Python extension is installed, along with python3.7.3 and flake8, pep8.

Comment: I think you're going to have to be more specific. Can you provide a screenshot?

Answer (score 16):

The Python extension for VS Code currently doesn't offer any quick fixes.

Comment: Is it..?? It's a disappointment. I am transitioning from atom to  VS code... I am missing this feature

Comment: @BhanuTez you will need to be more specific about what quick fixes you're after. And when you know which one(s) you specifically want, please either upvote a preexisting issue or open a new one at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python.

Comment: In Atom we have "beautify" extension that is supporting almost all languages. When I want to beautify my python. I can simply press ctrl+Alt+B this will beautify my python code(basically any code) according to pep8(even flake8 as well). This feature is missing in vs code.

Comment: @BhanuTez actually the Python extension has that via [formatter support](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_formatting).

Comment: How to disable Peek Problem in VS Code?

Answer (score 4):

**Solution for 2021.**

I got the same issue with Python for VSCode 1.54.2.

I solved it by installing the **Pylance** extension and making it the default Python language server (a message should pop up just after the installation asking if you want to make it the default Python language server). Now everything works flawlessly.

Comment: As helpful as it is, this answer needs extra elaboration. For one, does it have unintended side effects to people accustomed with the usual Python extension? Anything else people would need to expect other than "working flawlessly"?

Comment: Unfortunately, Pylance does not work with VS Codium (="Visual Studio without tracking"). Also see https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/791

Comment: this worked for me, though i had to go into settings and change the default Python language server manually.

Answer (score 3):

Python extension started to support Quick Fix.
First, function adding imports is supported.

[Python in Visual Studio Code – November 2019 Release | Python](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/python-in-visual-studio-code-november-2019-release/)

### **However**

Python extension ver.`2020.1.58038` and `2020.1.57204` have bug that it doesn't display Quick Fix.

### Solution

#### Plan A: Use old version of Python extension

1.

If you haven't install Python extension, install it once.

2.

Install ver.`2019.11.50794` or `2019.11.49689` by following steps in below answer.

[vs code - rollback extension/install specific extension version - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53755378/12721873)

#### Plan B: Use Insiders version of Python extension

1.

Install Visual Studio Code - Insiders.

[Download Visual Studio Code Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/)

2.

Install Python extension once, then click [Reload Required] button.

3.

Open Settings editor. (Ctrl + ,)

4.

Search by keyword: "Insiders Channel", then change pulldown to "daily" or "weekly",
and save Settings.
Then, Visual Studio Code start to download Insider version of Python extension.
(Below status bar displays progress)

5.

When popup message
"Please reload Visual Studio Code to use the insiders build of the Python extension."
is displayed, click [Reload] button.

### Requirement

Don't forget that there are two requirement to use Quick Fix feature.

- Use Microsoft Python Language Server
- Enable linting

#### Use Microsoft Python Language Server

Set `python.jediEnabled` to false in your [settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference) file.

#### Enable linting

1.

Open Command Palette. (View > Command Palette... or F1 or Ctrl + Shift + P)

2.

Run "Python: Enable Linting" command.

3.

Select "On" in the drop-down menu.

cf. [Editing Python Code in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_quick-fixes)

Answer (score 1):

I also recently tried the [Sourcery](https://sourcery.ai) VSCode Python Refactoring Extension to provide more refactorings that helps eliminate the errors in some cases implementing the line in question more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Having spent ages reading many articles on this, I've slightly improved my position.  The right mouse button never comes up with anything, but I can press Ctrl + a full stop (period if you're in the US) to bring up suggested imports - sometimes.

I have Pylance installed in VS Code (so do you probably), which should be the default linter, but just in case I forced this in VS Code Settings:

```
// Defines type of the language server (should default to Pylance if installed anyway)
    "python.languageServer": "Pylance",
```

The comments are mine.  But then I read the notes on PyLance, and it seems you have to enable this setting by adding these lines:

```
 // Offer auto-import completions.
    "python.analysis.autoImportCompletions": true,
```

Having said all of this, the feature has now stopped working again!  I've left this in just in case a) it gives anyone any ideas or b) I get it working again and can come back to edit this answer.

Answer (score 0):

For **import quick fixes**, there is a solution.

Use the following VsCode Extension which work just as expected.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Bar.python-import-helper

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, this is now supported, but I could not get it work. I tried upgrading VS Code, reinstalling Python extension and Pylance, switching to pre-release, reloading VS Code, making Pylance the default language server for Python etc. What did the trick finally was looking at my JSON settings and get rid of settings (both user and workspace) that were no longer supported / conflicting and similar. Basically all the ones that were highlighted when you open the JSON in VS Code itself. Then, after re-loading VS Code, it magically worked: When I moved my curse into the object definition (e.g. the name of the class), the bulb showed up after a second or two.

Comment: what settings did you remove? were they any that are related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/77283648/11107541 ?

Comment: I can’t remember but using binary segmentation, you can find the offending setting in log2(n) iterations. Maybe first remove all settings and see if my solution works for you.

Answer (score 0):

At least in VS Code 1.87.0 with installed Pylance v2024.2.2, it works in different ways, for example:

- type `path` and it automatically suggests to use method from a package

[image: auto popup]

- if you close popup or hover the cursor over the unknown work then run quick fix (`CTRL`+`.` on Windows/Linux or `CMD`+`.` on Mac or select it from the command palette):

[image: quick fix]

See also https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_quick-fixes