# Why Vscode is showing an "unable to import" error

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import, pylint, pylance

I have been looking all over the internet and spent hours trying to fix this.

**Summary of the issue:**

1. When importing a class/functions from a local module, I am getting an `Unable to import 'x' pylint (import-error)` (image #1)
2. Vscode is not suggesting a "quick-fix - auto import" to import an already installed library (pyngrok in this case) (image #2).
   [image: Error #1]
   [image: Error #2]

**What I tried:**

- Created a virtual env
- Selected the virtual env as Python interpreter in Vscode
- Installed Python-related extension: IntelliSense (Pylance)
- Installed pylint (`pip install pylint`) and selected it as a linter through Vs code
- Completely uninstall/reinstall Vscode (including caches and preferences)
- Reloaded the window (`cmd+shift+p` -> Developer: Reload window)
- Added `"env": {"PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceRoot}"}` to launch.json file
- Added `"python.linting.enabled": true` and `"python.analysis.autoImportCompletions": true` to settings.json file
- Went through the [Troubleshooting linting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_troubleshooting-linting)

**My project structure:**

```
my-app/
├─ venv/
├─ errors/
│  ├─ __init__.py
│  ├─ interface
├─ _app.py
├─ __init__.py
```

**Notes:**

- In the module I am importing from, I do have an `__init__.py` file
- When running the code, it works just fine, so the import-error error is not an actual error
- I don't want to solve it by just ignoring the import-error in the settings

**My system**

- MacOS 12.5.1
- System's Python version: 3.8
- Project's Python virtual environment version: 3.8.
- Vscode Version: 1.71.0

Comment: For the first question, please show your workspace directory structure. For the second question, according to an [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55582277/visual-studio-code-quick-fix-python) in 2019, the Python extension for VS Code currently doesn't offer any quick fixes.

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT Thanks. I was able to fix the first issue by simply deleting the __init__.py file from the root folder of my project. About the 2nd issue, kinda weird that they haven't fixed it since 2019, but I guess it is what it is. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the first issue by deleting the `__init__.py` file from the root folder of my project.

Regarding the second issue, as MingJie-MSFT commented - it is an [issue from 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55582277/visual-studio-code-quick-fix-python).

That being said - I was able to (partially) solve it, by installing the [Sourcery](https://sourcery.ai/) extension for vscode.