# Code Completion stopped working for "Java Extension Pack"

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, intellisense, intellicode

I am currently working on a Java project using the `Java Extension Pack` for VS Code. Thus plugin has been working for three weeks and now the auto completion has decided to stop for no reason.

Looking in the 'output' tab, I can see the following errors:

```
[Error - 1:56:31 PM] 23-Dec-2019 13:56:31 Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core".
org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.contentassist.CompletionProposalRequestor.<init>(Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/ICompilationUnit;I)V
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.contentassist.CompletionProposalRequestor.<init>(Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/ICompilationUnit;I)V
    at com.microsoft.jdtls.intellicode.core.CompletionProvider.initializeRequestor(CompletionProvider.java:133)
    at com.microsoft.jdtls.intellicode.core.CompletionProvider.computeContentAssist(CompletionProvider.java:89)
    at com.microsoft.jdtls.intellicode.core.CompletionProvider.provideCompletionItems(CompletionProvider.java:60)
    at com.microsoft.jdtls.intellicode.core.CommandHandler.executeCommand(CommandHandler.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.WorkspaceExecuteCommandHandler$1.run(WorkspaceExecuteCommandHandler.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.WorkspaceExecuteCommandHandler.executeCommand(WorkspaceExecuteCommandHandler.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.JDTLanguageServer.lambda$3(JDTLanguageServer.java:472)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.JDTLanguageServer.lambda$48(JDTLanguageServer.java:963)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:602)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:577)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.exec(CompletableFuture.java:443)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)

[Error - 1:56:31 PM] 23-Dec-2019 13:56:31 Error in calling delegate command handler
org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.contentassist.CompletionProposalRequestor.<init>(Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/ICompilationUnit;I)V
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.contentassist.CompletionProposalRequestor.<init>(Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/ICompilationUnit;I)V
    at com.microsoft.jdtls.intellicode.core.CompletionProvider.initializeRequestor(CompletionProvider.java:133)
    at com.microsoft.jdtls.intellicode.core.CompletionProvider.computeContentAssist(CompletionProvider.java:89)
    at com.microsoft.jdtls.intellicode.core.CompletionProvider.provideCompletionItems(CompletionProvider.java:60)
    at com.microsoft.jdtls.intellicode.core.CommandHandler.executeCommand(CommandHandler.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.WorkspaceExecuteCommandHandler$1.run(WorkspaceExecuteCommandHandler.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.WorkspaceExecuteCommandHandler.executeCommand(WorkspaceExecuteCommandHandler.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.JDTLanguageServer.lambda$3(JDTLanguageServer.java:472)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.JDTLanguageServer.lambda$48(JDTLanguageServer.java:963)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:602)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:577)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.exec(CompletableFuture.java:443)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)

[Error - 1:56:32 PM] 23-Dec-2019 13:56:32 Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core".
org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.contentassist.CompletionProposalRequestor.<init>(Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/ICompilationUnit;I)V
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.contentassist.CompletionProposalRequestor.<init>(Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/ICompilationUnit;I)V
    at com.microsoft.jdtls.intellicode.core.CompletionProvider.initializeRequestor(CompletionProvider.java:133)
    at com.microsoft.jdtls.intellicode.core.CompletionProvider.computeContentAssist(CompletionProvider.java:89)
    at com.microsoft.jdtls.intellicode.core.CompletionProvider.provideCompletionItems(CompletionProvider.java:60)
    at com.microsoft.jdtls.intellicode.core.CommandHandler.executeCommand(CommandHandler.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.WorkspaceExecuteCommandHandler$1.run(WorkspaceExecuteCommandHandler.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.WorkspaceExecuteCommandHandler.executeCommand(WorkspaceExecuteCommandHandler.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.JDTLanguageServer.lambda$3(JDTLanguageServer.java:472)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.JDTLanguageServer.lambda$48(JDTLanguageServer.java:963)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:602)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:577)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.exec(CompletableFuture.java:443)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)

[Error - 1:56:32 PM] 23-Dec-2019 13:56:32 Error in calling delegate command handler
org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.contentassist.CompletionProposalRequestor.<init>(Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/ICompilationUnit;I)V
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.contentassist.CompletionProposalRequestor.<init>(Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/ICompilationUnit;I)V
    at com.microsoft.jdtls.intellicode.core.CompletionProvider.initializeRequestor(CompletionProvider.java:133)
    at com.microsoft.jdtls.intellicode.core.CompletionProvider.computeContentAssist(CompletionProvider.java:89)
    at com.microsoft.jdtls.intellicode.core.CompletionProvider.provideCompletionItems(CompletionProvider.java:60)
    at com.microsoft.jdtls.intellicode.core.CommandHandler.executeCommand(CommandHandler.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.WorkspaceExecuteCommandHandler$1.run(WorkspaceExecuteCommandHandler.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.WorkspaceExecuteCommandHandler.executeCommand(WorkspaceExecuteCommandHandler.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.JDTLanguageServer.lambda$3(JDTLanguageServer.java:472)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.JDTLanguageServer.lambda$48(JDTLanguageServer.java:963)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:602)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:577)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.exec(CompletableFuture.java:443)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)

[Error - 1:57:37 PM] 23-Dec-2019 13:57:37 Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core".
org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.contentassist.CompletionProposalRequestor.<init>(Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/ICompilationUnit;I)V
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.contentassist.CompletionProposalRequestor.<init>(Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/ICompilationUnit;I)V
    at com.microsoft.jdtls.intellicode.core.CompletionProvider.initializeRequestor(CompletionProvider.java:133)
    at com.microsoft.jdtls.intellicode.core.CompletionProvider.computeContentAssist(CompletionProvider.java:89)
    at com.microsoft.jdtls.intellicode.core.CompletionProvider.provideCompletionItems(CompletionProvider.java:60)
    at com.microsoft.jdtls.intellicode.core.CommandHandler.executeCommand(CommandHandler.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.WorkspaceExecuteCommandHandler$1.run(WorkspaceExecuteCommandHandler.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.WorkspaceExecuteCommandHandler.executeCommand(WorkspaceExecuteCommandHandler.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.JDTLanguageServer.lambda$3(JDTLanguageServer.java:472)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.JDTLanguageServer.lambda$48(JDTLanguageServer.java:963)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:602)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:577)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.exec(CompletableFuture.java:443)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)

[Error - 1:57:37 PM] 23-Dec-2019 13:57:37 Error in calling delegate command handler
org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.contentassist.CompletionProposalRequestor.<init>(Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/ICompilationUnit;I)V
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.contentassist.CompletionProposalRequestor.<init>(Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/ICompilationUnit;I)V
    at com.microsoft.jdtls.intellicode.core.CompletionProvider.initializeRequestor(CompletionProvider.java:133)
    at com.microsoft.jdtls.intellicode.core.CompletionProvider.computeContentAssist(CompletionProvider.java:89)
    at com.microsoft.jdtls.intellicode.core.CompletionProvider.provideCompletionItems(CompletionProvider.java:60)
    at com.microsoft.jdtls.intellicode.core.CommandHandler.executeCommand(CommandHandler.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.WorkspaceExecuteCommandHandler$1.run(WorkspaceExecuteCommandHandler.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.WorkspaceExecuteCommandHandler.executeCommand(WorkspaceExecuteCommandHandler.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.JDTLanguageServer.lambda$3(JDTLanguageServer.java:472)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.JDTLanguageServer.lambda$48(JDTLanguageServer.java:963)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:602)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:577)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.exec(CompletableFuture.java:443)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)

[Error - 1:57:37 PM] 23-Dec-2019 13:57:37 Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core".
org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.contentassist.CompletionProposalRequestor.<init>(Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/ICompilationUnit;I)V
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.contentassist.CompletionProposalRequestor.<init>(Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/ICompilationUnit;I)V
    at com.microsoft.jdtls.intellicode.core.CompletionProvider.initializeRequestor(CompletionProvider.java:133)
    at com.microsoft.jdtls.intellicode.core.CompletionProvider.computeContentAssist(CompletionProvider.java:89)
    at com.microsoft.jdtls.intellicode.core.CompletionProvider.provideCompletionItems(CompletionProvider.java:60)
    at com.microsoft.jdtls.intellicode.core.CommandHandler.executeCommand(CommandHandler.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.WorkspaceExecuteCommandHandler$1.run(WorkspaceExecuteCommandHandler.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.WorkspaceExecuteCommandHandler.executeCommand(WorkspaceExecuteCommandHandler.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.JDTLanguageServer.lambda$3(JDTLanguageServer.java:472)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.JDTLanguageServer.lambda$48(JDTLanguageServer.java:963)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:602)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:577)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.exec(CompletableFuture.java:443)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)

[Error - 1:57:37 PM] 23-Dec-2019 13:57:37 Error in calling delegate command handler
org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.contentassist.CompletionProposalRequestor.<init>(Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/ICompilationUnit;I)V
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.contentassist.CompletionProposalRequestor.<init>(Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/ICompilationUnit;I)V
    at com.microsoft.jdtls.intellicode.core.CompletionProvider.initializeRequestor(CompletionProvider.java:133)
    at com.microsoft.jdtls.intellicode.core.CompletionProvider.computeContentAssist(CompletionProvider.java:89)
    at com.microsoft.jdtls.intellicode.core.CompletionProvider.provideCompletionItems(CompletionProvider.java:60)
    at com.microsoft.jdtls.intellicode.core.CommandHandler.executeCommand(CommandHandler.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.WorkspaceExecuteCommandHandler$1.run(WorkspaceExecuteCommandHandler.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.WorkspaceExecuteCommandHandler.executeCommand(WorkspaceExecuteCommandHandler.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.JDTLanguageServer.lambda$3(JDTLanguageServer.java:472)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.JDTLanguageServer.lambda$48(JDTLanguageServer.java:963)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:602)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:577)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.exec(CompletableFuture.java:443)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)

[Error - 1:57:38 PM] 23-Dec-2019 13:57:38 Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core".
org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.contentassist.CompletionProposalRequestor.<init>(Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/ICompilationUnit;I)V
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.contentassist.CompletionProposalRequestor.<init>(Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/ICompilationUnit;I)V
    at com.microsoft.jdtls.intellicode.core.CompletionProvider.initializeRequestor(CompletionProvider.java:133)
    at com.microsoft.jdtls.intellicode.core.CompletionProvider.computeContentAssist(CompletionProvider.java:89)
    at com.microsoft.jdtls.intellicode.core.CompletionProvider.provideCompletionItems(CompletionProvider.java:60)
    at com.microsoft.jdtls.intellicode.core.CommandHandler.executeCommand(CommandHandler.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.WorkspaceExecuteCommandHandler$1.run(WorkspaceExecuteCommandHandler.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.WorkspaceExecuteCommandHandler.executeCommand(WorkspaceExecuteCommandHandler.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.JDTLanguageServer.lambda$3(JDTLanguageServer.java:472)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.JDTLanguageServer.lambda$48(JDTLanguageServer.java:963)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:602)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:577)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.exec(CompletableFuture.java:443)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)

[Error - 1:57:38 PM] 23-Dec-2019 13:57:38 Error in calling delegate command handler
org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.contentassist.CompletionProposalRequestor.<init>(Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/ICompilationUnit;I)V
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.contentassist.CompletionProposalRequestor.<init>(Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/ICompilationUnit;I)V
    at com.microsoft.jdtls.intellicode.core.CompletionProvider.initializeRequestor(CompletionProvider.java:133)
    at com.microsoft.jdtls.intellicode.core.CompletionProvider.computeContentAssist(CompletionProvider.java:89)
    at com.microsoft.jdtls.intellicode.core.CompletionProvider.provideCompletionItems(CompletionProvider.java:60)
    at com.microsoft.jdtls.intellicode.core.CommandHandler.executeCommand(CommandHandler.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.WorkspaceExecuteCommandHandler$1.run(WorkspaceExecuteCommandHandler.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.WorkspaceExecuteCommandHandler.executeCommand(WorkspaceExecuteCommandHandler.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.JDTLanguageServer.lambda$3(JDTLanguageServer.java:472)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.JDTLanguageServer.lambda$48(JDTLanguageServer.java:963)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:602)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:577)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.exec(CompletableFuture.java:443)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
```

What's going on here and is there anything I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last version of "Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat" extension throws errors and break code completion.

Temporary solution is to go back to previous version of this extensions.
This worked for me.

Note: I see new version is released this morning. I've installed it and problem is solved now.

**So try to upgrade to 0.55.1 and see if it's solved now.**

Comment: Thank you so much! It must have updated automatically. Reverted to previous version (0.54.2) and it works!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an incompatibility between the latest "Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat" version (`0.55`) and the "Visual Studio IntelliCode" extension (`1.2.2`).

You can try temporarily reverting to the previous version of the Language support extension (`0.54.2`) as suggested by Frax04 (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53755378/4687028) for how to do so), or you can also temporarily disable the "Visual Studio IntelliCode" extension.

This issue is currently tracked in the `vscode-java` GitHub repo : https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/1213