# VS Code "Run selection/line in Python interactive window" not working at all

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-interactive, vscode-python

On a new install of VS Code on a new machine I have come across this error.

The send to python interactive window functionality is behaving exceptionally weirdly.

**It will:**
- Send a single line of code to the interactive window using either shift+enter or right-click and select, when the cursor is on that line.

**It will not:**
- Send any code to the interactive window when code is selected (by highlighting) either through shift+enter or right click and select.

I have ticked the box is settings marked "Python > Data Science: Send Selection To Interactive Window".

Anyone else experienced this problem or have suggestions to fix it?

*VS Code version: 1.14.1*

*Python version: 3.7.4*

*Python VS code extension: 2020.1.57204*

Comment: were tracking the issue here if you have any more input: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/174426
I haven't been able to reproduce this myself

Answer (score 3):

After some searching I have found that there is an issue with the Python VS Code Extension version 202.1.57204.

The solution to this is to install the previous version in VS Code (209.11.50794).

To do this go to the extensions tab on the left side, right click on the "Python" extension and select "Install another version...". Any previous version should work, but I chose the most recent before 2020.1.507204.

Comment: There's a gif on how to do this in the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53755378/7615751