# vscode 'jupyter run selection/line in interactive window' shortcut not working

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I want to use a keyboard shortcut for `jupyter run selection/kine in interactive window` in `vscode` but it's not working.

I also checked [VS Code "Run selection/line in Python interactive window" not working at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59678010/vs-code-run-selection-line-in-python-interactive-window-not-working-at-all) which implies that there is a version problem but I don't have that version(my version is `v2022.4.1`), besides it says "it's not working at all" but mine is working when I right click and click on "Run selection/line in Python interactive window".

the when expression also follows by `editorTextFocus && isWorkspaceTrusted && jupyter.ownsSelection && !findInputFocussed && !notebookEditorFocused && !replaceInputFocussed && editorLangId == 'python'`

by the way there is no other conflict wit my key bindings. so is there any way to solve this?

Comment: This works for me : `"jupyter.interactiveWindow.textEditor.executeSelection": true`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite this working for me via a right click, i still had to select this in the GUI version of settings -> Jupyter: Send Selection To Interactive Window. Then my chosen keybinding also worked. This solution was found and explained more fully at:

https://superuser.com/questions/1461655/vs-code-shiftenter-does-not-send-code-to-python-interactive-why

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to switch the shortcut of this command? Maybe some other programs occupy this shortcut.

Comment: Ive tried 2 combinations, but again I would check it