# VSCode Interactive Window "Run selection/line in Interactive Window" stopped working

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ipython

I face the same problem as [VS Code "Run selection/line in Python interactive window" not working at all](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59678010/14976775), yet using Bisect to disable and detect the reasons through extensions didn't help. For me the problem started after VScode itself was updated yesterday.

VS Code version: 1.75.1
Python version: 3.9.13
Python VS Code extension: 2023.2.0

This command "**Shift + Enter**" just stopped working in full all of a sudden. It runs for a **single** line selected, but not for **multiple**. I cannot find why.

It is just time consuming to copy and paste the same code in the interactive code to run it.
Any ideas how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just looking into the dev tools I recognized the problem. I had for whatever reason a package installed `googleapis_common_protos` which was blocking the implementation. After uninstalling that package, the problem is resolved.

Now I can run again a selection in interactive Jupyter window.

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to be caused by the 1.75.1 update. I solved this problem by using the old version of vscode. You can install [the old version of vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_74) here.

By the way, you can also submit the problem to [github/VsCode](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues) for repair.