# How to downgrade the VS Code powershell extension?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code for powershell development, but it becomes increasingly difficult to use VS Code as powershell IDE due to frequent upgrades that just do not work.

So, my question is - how to downgrade VS Code Powershell extension? I know VS Code does not support downgrades, but it seems possible to install an extension manually having its vsix file. So, basically I am asking - where can I download the older installations?

Comment: Does this work, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42626065/vs-code-rollback-extension-install-specific-extension-version/53755378?r=SearchResults&s=1|44.8536#53755378 if you are using an actual installed extension.  Or perhaps you are just referring to built-in functionality and not a separate extension?  If a separate extension, you should be able to rollback to an earlier version.

Comment: @Mark - That exactly it. My question is a duplicate. Voting to close.