# Visual studio code python extension fails when I run format

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I keep getting this error when I try to format in vscode:

```
Traceback: ...
...pyvsc-run-isolated.py", line 30, in <module>
```

How do I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by downgrading the python extension in vscode to `v2020.1.58038`.
Check out this post to see how that can be done:
[vs code - rollback extension/install specific extension version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42626065/vs-code-rollback-extension-install-specific-extension-version)