# VSCode Download Older version of an Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter

I'm looking to install an older version of the VSCode [jupyter extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter). (The reason is that I'm using a VSCode build from [Code Server](https://github.com/cdr/code-server) which is as of VSCode v1.57.1 - released this summer - and I'd like to install extensions for it). It looks like the [Jupyter Extension version 2021.6.9999](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/blob/2021.6.9999/package.json#L27) is the newest version of the Jupyterhub plugin that supports VSCode version v1.57.1.

However, the marketplace only displays the last 5 extension versions under the "[Version History](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter&ssr=false#version-history)" section of the landing page. These versions listed are all too new.

I'm able to find the [source code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/releases/tag/2021.6.9999) for Jupyter version 2021.6.9999 on Github, but the vsix binaries are not there. I'm not sure how to compile it; seems like it'd be a pretty involved process.

Is there an archive of the vsix plugin files going back further than just 5 releases? Those versions were available earlier this year, so it seems like there should be a way to access the older vsix extensions somewhere. Any thoughts is much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Marketplace not showing the older versions, but you can download `.vsix` files from marketplace anyway.

Copy below link and paste your browser, it will download jupyter
version `2021.6.999662501`, you can download any `vsix` binary with this method, just change version name from URL.

```
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery/publishers/ms-toolsai/vsextensions/jupyter/2021.6.999662501/vspackage
```

Also, there is a site to download older `vsix` files: https://www.vsixhub.com/history/43174/

## How can find the version number?

I research the source code and see version number format `<year>.<month>.<build_number>` from here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/blob/main/CONTRIBUTING.md#versioning

GitHub Actions create releases and upload to marketplace when triggered. There is no human interaction. If you research Github Actions pipelines you can find version numbers. For an example:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/runs/3765342614?check_suite_focus=true#step:7:169

Comment: Thank you very much @ridvanaltun!  How were you able to find the "662501" portion of that version number? The git tag just has the 2021.6.999. Did you find the version on vsixhub and then that's how you knew the version to hack into the url?

Comment: Because I'm 10x developer :p, kidding, I updated the answer.

Comment: @ridvanaltun Is there a more elegant way to check this? What if the extension does not have a reliable changelog?

Comment: sorry @kyrlon, i don't know any other options

Comment: @ridvanaltun got an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76559642/13642249) btw!

Comment: Is there a generic way to form that download link from marketplace? For example what if I wanted to download an older version of the python extension?

Answer (score 5):

A newer VSCode feature makes it easier.

Right click on the extension in the Extension tab. It will display an option "Install another version". From this menu you can install the desired version.

Since version 1.75 it won't autoupgrade the extension if it was pinned to an older version ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53755378/10335)).

Answer (score 1):

You can try

1. Go to https://web.archive.org/
2. Search for the package using original marketplace URL
3. Click on a date
4. Right click on download button and copy the URL
5. Remove everything before HTTPS://
6. Open remaining URL in browser

Cheers :)

Example

1. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AndersLaublaubplusco.SitecoreHelixVisualStudioTemplates
2. https://web.archive.org/web/20210116094649/https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AndersLaublaubplusco.SitecoreHelixVisualStudioTemplates
3. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AndersLaublaubplusco.SitecoreHelixVisualStudioTemplates

search for respective date