# How do I list extensions installed from VSIX?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodium

I'm using Codium with some extensions I installed from VSIX since they're not available on Open VSX. I want to get a list of them (so that, for example, I can check if they've been added to Open VSX or check for updates), but I can't figure out how to do that easily. The only way I've found is to go through all extensions one-by-one and check if they have a Marketplace link (or other marketplace info like install count).

**Research**

- Managing Extensions in Visual Studio Code

  - [§ Install from a VSIX](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace#_install-from-a-vsix) - only says how to install and nothing after that
  - [§ Extensions view filters](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace#_extensions-view-filters) - There doesn't seem to be a filter for this
  - [§ List installed extensions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace#_list-installed-extensions)
- VSCodium docs [§ Extensions + Marketplace](https://github.com/VSCodium/vscodium/blob/master/docs/index.md#extensions--marketplace) - refers to MS docs
- `codium --help` § Extensions Management

  - `codium --list-extensions` just shows names, no details. I also tried adding `--show-versions` and `--verbose`

Comment: Just to be clear, I've written an answer and accepted it, but I'm fully open to other solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the user `extensions.json` file, it looks like ones that were installed from VSIX don't have a `uuid` under `identifier` and have very little `metadata` (e.g. no `id`).

In my case, the file is at `~/.vscode-oss/extensions/extensions.json` and this [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) command gets the list:

```bash
file=~/.vscode-oss/extensions/extensions.json
jq -r '.[] | select(.identifier.uuid == null) | .identifier.id' "$file" | sort
```

(For the opposite, use `!= null`.)

---

Then I found out [you can use `vsce` to query the VSCode Marketplace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76559642/4518341) and the equivalent for Open VSX is [`ovsx`](https://github.com/eclipse/openvsx/blob/master/cli/README.md), e.g.

```bash
vsce show "$name"
ovsx get --metadata "$name"
```

So to check if any were published on Open VSX after I installed them, I wrote this Bash script that'll go through the VSIX ones and check if they're on the marketplace, plus double-check the non-VSIX ones:

```bash
file=~/.vscode-oss/extensions/extensions.json

for operator in '==' '!='; do
    condition=".identifier.uuid $operator null"
    echo "$condition"
    jq -r ".[] | select($condition) | .identifier.id" "$file" |
        sort |
        while read -r name
    do
        if ovsx get --metadata "$name" > /dev/null; then
            echo "Found: $name"
        fi  # Otherwise ovsx prints an error
    done
    echo
done
```

This identified one extension, so I uninstalled it and reinstalled it from the Marketplace, and after it has a `.identifier.uuid`, which seems to confirm this method works! I noticed though, it already had a Marketplace link, so I suppose it would have updated automatically, but no updates were published since I installed it.

---

Lastly, just to be sure, I did check that all the names in `extensions.json` match `codium --list-extensions`.