# unable to install 'rangav.vscode-thunder-client' extension because it is not compatible with current version of vscode (version 1.52.1)

Tags: visual-studio-code, thunderclient

when I am trying to install Thunder Client for vscode, I am getting this error. And not able to install it.

**error while installing 'thunder-client' extension
unable to install 'rangav.vscode-thunder-client' extension because it is not compatible with current version of vscode (version 1.52.1)**

I am not able to find which version of vscode I need to install to make it compatible with thunder client. Do I need to upgrade or downgrade? Or are there other versions of thunder client available?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to either downgrade the extension version, or upgrade your VS Code. For downloading older versions of extensions, see [VS Code - how to rollback extension/install specific extension version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42626065/11107541) and [VSCode Download Older version of an Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69398500/11107541). For upgrading VS Code, use the `Code: Check for Updates` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette), or just re-download and re-install.