How to Find and Download a Specific Extension Version for an Offline VSCode Installation
I am working in an environment without internet access and need to install extensions on Visual Studio Code offline. My current approach involves downloading .vsix files from the VSCode Marketplace on an internet-enabled machine, transferring them to the offline environment, and then installing them on my local VSCode instance.
However, I am running into an issue because my version of VSCode is outdated due to the offline constraints, and not all the latest extensions are compatible with it.
Is there a way to find and download a specific version of an extension that is compatible with my older VSCode version?

Nothing special I think. Just download the versions from "Version History" tab of the extension page on Marketplace (like https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitHub.copilot), and then unpack/check which one works for your specific VS Code version.

The Marketplace contains only the last 5 versions, and sometimes a certain VSCode version needs a certain extension version.  So I need a table (or kind of API) that I can map between the VSCode version (or VSCode commit ID) and the extension version and also I need a way to download the extension with the required version

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69398500/vscode-download-older-version-of-an-extension.
