# VSCode: How to fix Python extension version for Python 2 compatibility and prevent automatic upgrade?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-python

I have a legacy code using Python 2. The last version of VSCode Python extension that supports Python 2 is *v2022.2.1924087327*

It is very easy to [change the extension to an older version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42626065/vs-code-how-to-rollback-extension-install-specific-extension-version).

My problem is that VSCode always automatically updates the extension. Since I'm using it in a remote machine, when I loose connection, it automatically updates the extension, and I must manually downgrade it, reload the window and start it again.

Is it possible to fiz the version of my Python extension in VSCode?

Comment: until that version is no longer available at the Marketplace, better to download the VSIX from the Marketplace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just found how to [prevent extensions to automatically upgrade](https://www.nicoespeon.com/en/2020/10/prevent-vscode-extensions-automatic-updates/).

And I just set:

```
{
  "extensions.autoUpdate": false
}
```

It will now ask me for each extension upgrade, it is an annoyance, but at least I can control it.

If someone finds how to disable auto update just for the Python extension, I'll mark it as the correct answer.