# How to debug Python 2.7 code with VS Code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, debugging, visual-studio-code

For work I have to use Python 2.7.

But when I use the "debug my python file" function in VS Code, I get an error.

Even with a simple program, like :

```
print()
```

Comment: you have to install a previous version of the ms-python extension, they dropped python2 support a few months back

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As rioV8 said in a comment, **you have to install a previous version of the Python extension**, because in the meanwhile support for Python 2 has been dropped.

To [install a previous version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42626065/vs-code-how-to-rollback-extension-install-specific-extension-version) you have to:

1. Open the Extensions pane from the bar on the left and find Python
2. Click on the gear icon and select "**Install another version**"
3. Choose **2021.9.1246542782**.
4. After it's finished, restart VS Code.

---

If you want to understand why you need version 2021.9.1246542782:

The component that provides support to the language is [Jedi](https://pypi.org/project/jedi/), and the [release notes](https://pypi.org/project/jedi/#changelog) of version 0.17.2 (2020-07-17) say that

> This will be the last release that supports Python 2 and Python 3.5.
> `0.18.0` will be Python 3.6+.

And according to the release notes of the Python extension, the latest version that was based on Jedi 0.17 was 2021.9.3 (20 September 2021), because the following one ([2021.10.0, 7 October 2021](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/ms-python.python/changelog#user-content-2021.10.0-(7-october-2021))) says

> Phase out Jedi 0.17

Is that all? No, because the selection that VS Code offers when selecting previous versions uses a different numbering scheme. Anyway, the latest one of the v2021.9.* branch is v2021.9.1246542782, which I suppose corresponds to 2021.9.3, so it's the one you need.

Comment: In step 2, if you already have another version of the plugin installed, it should be "Click on the 'V' next to 'Uninstall' (More Actions...) and select 'Install another version'"

Comment: Before install - uninstall pylance, otherwise the install will be blocked.