# Is there way to debug a Python 2.7 app that has been created with Buildout in vscode?

Tags: python, python-2.7, visual-studio-code, debugging, vscode-debugger

I have a legacy system that uses Python 2.7. The application gets built using [Buildout](https://www.buildout.org/en/latest/contents.html#) and I run the application as `bin/django runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` oppose to `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`. Is it possible to debug something like this? I have referred to the following post: [How to debug Python 2.7 code with VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72214043/how-to-debug-python-2-7-code-with-vs-code) But I can't seem to get a working `.vscode/launch.json` configuration to work. I am running the application in a Docker container which I attach my vscode instance to. I am not trying to to debug the running web server, but the background tasks that the webserver performs using celery. Example: `bin/django test_task TaskName --start`

I appreciate all of those who reply in advance, thanks!

Comment: VSC has dropped support for Python 2.7, you have to find a different dev environment, maybe Komodo

Answer (score 0):

The python extension in vscode provides support for **python 3.7** and above.

You need to downgrade the Python extension or even the vscode version until it is suitable for **python 2.7** debugging,

[image]

related links:

- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python#python-extension-for-visual-studio-code
- https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy/issues/884
- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/18969