# vs code, render the inline color decorators and color picker outline

Tags: visual-studio-code, decorator, colorbox

I was use vs code for a while, I was happy to see my decorator colors and color picker outline the code, but someday I just update the vs code, I don't know when that is happen, so I saw the box color between my code, I did not like it at all, so I tried so hard to make as old, I did research and googled it but not lucky to find out how to make it as old again.
see my screenshot so you can understand what I want. Thank you.
[image: see this is my problem]

I tried to change the settings but if I uncheck this open option that color box is disappear, [image: settings]

Comment: how did you get the screenshot of the old behaviour? What version were you running to get that screenshot? Was it a version older than 1.18? (related: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_18#_faster-editor-decorations and https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_16#_cssjson-color-preview). older than 1.3? (related: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/june_2016#_add-decorations-before-and-after-text)

Comment: can you please provide a code block to ease reproducing the issue? Also, I'm starting to think this might be an extension-specific behaviour/change. Did you have different versions of Dart/Flutter-related extensions in between taking those two screenshots?

Comment: @user sorry for late, the old screen I did the capture long time ago, about 3 years and then I got some busy so I did not know when the behavior changed. and I come back to develop old apps of mine and find the vs code looks like new screen inline color. I think its was an extension but I really don't know which extension. thank you.

Comment: It's probably a change in behaviour of the Dart extension. You can try older versions to find where the behaviour changed: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42626065/11107541

Comment: thank you but I'm afraid that I just mess-up every thing, now days I'm building new app and I don't want to do some mistakes thank you again.