# Why opens Visual Studio Code a second Python terminal and breaks the first?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal, anaconda

Since this morning, my Visual Studio Code (on Macbook Pro, M1-chip) rather brusquely started behaving differently.

If I now run code from a Python script line by line in the Python terminal (see attached gif):

1. a new terminal window opens. In this terminal Visual Studio Code correctly launches my preferred Python (3.10.9 (conda)) distribution.
2. Yet, it then quickly breaks this terminal process and opens a new one. In this second instance, Python is not launched, but the Python commands are sent to this new terminal, which self-evidently produces an error.
3. Then, if I launch Python in my second terminal manually, I can continue with the script.

Why does this happen? And what can I do to get it back to how it always has been? Just one terminal that opens...

For what it's worth, I am sharing here my `terminal.integrated.profile.osx`

```
{
"terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false,
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "zsh",
"terminal.integrated.automationProfile.osx": {},
"terminal.integrated.profiles.osx": {
    
    "bash": {
        "path": "bash",
        "args": [
            "-l"
        ],
        "icon": "terminal-bash"
    },
    "zsh": {
        "path": "zsh",
        "args": [
            "-l"
        ]
    },
    "fish": {
        "path": "fish",
        "args": [
            "-l"
        ]
    },
    "tmux": {
        "path": "tmux",
        "icon": "terminal-tmux"
    },
    "pwsh": {
        "path": "pwsh",
        "icon": "terminal-powershell"
    }
}
```

}

Hope you can help me out[image]

Comment: Oh sweet lord!!! Thank you so much starball! This saved me another sleepless night!! Downgrading to v.2023.8.0 works!

Answer (score 1):

So @starball 's answer was the fix.
This issue was raised Yesterday here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76453447/11107541

The fix is downgrading the Python extension in Visual Studio Code to v.2023.8.0