# VSCode JSON to YAML auto conversion on save

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, yaml

I normally design aws step functions in Workflow Studio and copy the json file back into my source code control.

Up until about a month ago, if I paste the statemachine JSON code into file_name.asl.yml, something auto converts the json into yaml.

I'm not sure what extension was doing the auto conversion.
I have these extensions:

- AWS Toolkit (Amazon Web Services)
- YAML (Red Hat)

But it is no longer the case recently. Now, if I paste json, it just save it as json.

Anyone know which extension was doing the json->yaml conversion on save?

Comment: You can try testing older versions of those extensions. https://stackoverflow.com/q/42626065/11107541. You can also do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it. Let us know what you find.

Comment: YAML is a superset of JSON so „converting JSON to YAML“ is a no-op. Your JSON data is already valid YAML.