# VSCode code turn white while encountering an output error

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

when i encounter an error on my ipynb, i often get this error on my notebook cell code[image: vscode code text turn weird]

i'm not sure if it has something to do with blackformatter or not, in fact i never get this kind of error while working on .py files, only on .ipynb

[image: error logs]

[image: expected display]
i need to restart my vscode to get it back to normal

Comment: there is an issue with PyLance syntax highlighting, try an older version

Comment: possibly https://stackoverflow.com/q/76874235/11107541 ?