# View value in Data Viewer stopped showing - view Dataframes

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Yesterday it worked, but now it has stopped working. 
[image: Menu]
It's probably something simple that I've missed. I've restarted the computer, checked that I have Jupyter installed, and even tried reinstalling it. Any tips?

Edit: Added code

```
import pandas as pd
# Define the data
data = {'Name': ['John', 'Emma', 'Michael', 'Sophia'],
        'Age': [25, 28, 32, 30],
        'City': ['New York', 'London', 'Paris', 'Tokyo']}
# Create the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: did you run the code that created the data ?

Comment: show the code or a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Added code to the original post.

Comment: Continued to investigate. Have also reinstalled Python etc. but no progress. Is it some way to clear Vscode without re-install it?

Comment: How come it doesn't work? Isn't it normal in your picture? Also, are you using jupyter or py script for debugging?

Comment: I use jupyter  in vscode without any problems. Previously I have experienced that multiprocessing and vscode not is compatible. But no multiprocessing in this code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug with the recent release of VS Code 1.86 and the January 2024 release of the Python extension, which also moved a bunch of its debug functionality to the separate debugpy extension. See issue ticket [Data Viewer Not Working in Debug Mode #15121](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/15121)

The fix is made in PR [register watcher for new debugger type #15141](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/pull/15141), which is available in release patch v2024.1.1.

[One user found that](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/15121#issuecomment-1929104033) if they rolled back their Python-related extensions, the data viewer started working again: uninstall the debugpy extension, roll back Python extension to v2023.18.0, roll back Jupyter extension to v2023.9.1102792234. See als. [VS Code - how to rollback extension/install specific extension version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42626065/11107541).