# "View in Data Viewer" in VS Code not available (without jupyter)

Tags: python, dataframe, visual-studio-code, dataview

I set up python and vs code(3.10.2) on a new computer (1.86.0) and now the data viewer does not work anymore. It used to work like the guy explains in this video, without (jupyter). Just right click a variable during debugging, choose "view in data viewer and it opens in a new window. This was very convenient for dataframes and arrays. I did not install a specific extension. It was alway available. I tried reinstall pyton and vscode but did not work.

Comment: what do you mean "without jupyter"? you mean you're running a python script that isn't in a notebook?

Comment: Like This guy is demonstrating:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m1n4IJgdwco

Comment: dup probably. see my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/q/77931440/11107541

Answer (score 0):

`view in data viewer` is provided by [Jupyter extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter).

You have to install it.

Comment: Jupyter is installed anyhow. As far as I know with Jupyter you have to create a Jupyter environment to use it. I was using it as a feature of VS Code, like this guy shows in this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m1n4IJgdwco

Comment: @HannesHeisenberg I checked it. Yes, this is a bug that exists at the moment, you can try using the old version of python extension, or use `.ipynb` file to view the data.