# Unable to See "View Value in Data Viewer" Option in VS Code Debugger

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code, jupyter

I'm currently encountering an issue with Visual Studio Code where the "View Value in Data Viewer" option is not appearing in the debugger. This issue persists even though I have the Jupyter extension installed. Below are the details of my VS Code setup and the extensions I have installed:

```
VS Code Version: 1.85.2 (Commit:    8b3775030ed1a69b13e4f4c628c612102e30a681, Architecture: x64)    
Installed Extensions (relevant to Python and Jupyter):    
Jupyter-related extensions: 
ms-toolsai.jupyter@2023.11.1100101639    
ms-toolsai.jupyter-keymap@1.1.2 
ms-toolsai.jupyter-renderers@1.0.17    
ms-toolsai.vscode-jupyter-cell-tags@0.1.8    
ms-toolsai.vscode-jupyter-slideshow@0.1.5 
Python-related extensions:    
ms-python.python@2024.0.0 
ms-python.vscode-pylance@2023.12.1    
ms-python.autopep8@2023.8.0 
ms-python.black-formatter@2024.0.0    
ms-python.debugpy@2024.0.0 
ms-python.flake8@2023.10.0
```

Here's a screenshot of my current debugger view where the option is missing:
[image: debugger view]

here is my vs-code settings.json file :

```
{
    "go.useLanguageServer": true,
    "go.autocompleteUnimportedPackages": true,
    "go.formatTool": "gofmt",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "go.testFlags": [
        "-v"
    ],
    "explorer.decorations.badges": false,
    "window.titleBarStyle": "custom",
    "editor.minimap.size": "fill",
    "terminal.integrated.enableMultiLinePasteWarning": false,
    "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
    "files.autoSaveDelay": 10000,
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": false,
    "[python]": {
        "editor.formatOnType": false,
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.autopep8",
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    },
    "autopep8.args": [
        "--aggressive"
    ],
    "editor.renderWhitespace": "all",
    "http.proxy": "http://COMPANY.proxy.COMPANY.fr:3838",
    "markdownConverter.ConversionType": [
        "HTML",
        "PDF"
    ],
    "python.experiments.enabled": true,
    "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
    "python.analysis.autoImportCompletions": true,
    "python.analysis.completeFunctionParens": true,
    "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
    "flake8.args": [
        "--max-line-length=190",
        "--ignore=E402,F841,F401,W503,E721,E203,E501",
        // "--ignore=E402,F841,F401,E302,E305",
    ],
    // "black-formatter.args": [
    //     "--line-length=130"
    // ],
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "python.languageServer": "Pylance",
    "python.analysis.indexing": true,
    "python.analysis.typeCheckingMode": "off"
}
```

I've tried the usual troubleshooting steps like restarting VS Code, reinstalling the extensions, and checking for updates, but the problem persists. I'm wondering if there are specific settings or configurations I might be missing.

Could anyone provide insights or suggestions on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: dup probably. see my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/q/77931440/11107541

Comment: indeed, I didn't see those issues, thanks I will have a look