# VSCode Data Viewer button isn't there

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm following the VSCode tutorial for [Python and Data Science](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/data-science-tutorial) and have successfully installed the Jupyter and Python extensions. However, the Data Viewer isn't available for me to open in the Variables window in steps 6 & 7 of the tutorial.

I've restarted VSCode and uninstalled/reinstalled all extensions and am still experiencing the same issue. Any suggestions?

[image: VSCode screenshot]

Comment: is it in under the three dot menu? (it might be if your screen is narrow)

Comment: I wonder if this has any relation to https://stackoverflow.com/q/77931440/11107541. do you get the same issue as in that question post?