# Visual Studio Code not showing local variables for autocompletion (IntelliSense issue) after February 2024 auto-update

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am facing issues with Visual Studio Code auto-completion not properly working after latest update (February 2024).
I am using MacOS (M1) Monteray

To fully illustrate the problem, acqually I was having this problem since the first time I used VS code (using the configuration file reported below).
Then after December 2023 update, auto-completion was automatically fixed (without any modification to the configuration file).
Now, starting from a few days ago, after the latest VS Code update, I have the same problem I had before.

Here I copy-paste my whole configuration file (settings.json but I'm censoring the actual paths).

```json
{
    "editor.fontSize": 14,
    "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 14,
    "window.restoreWindows": "none",
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",

    "C_Cpp.autocomplete": "default",
    "C_Cpp.default.compilerPath": "~/CENSORED",
    "C_Cpp.default.includePath": [
        "~/CENSORED",
        "~/CENSORED",
        "~/CENSORED"
    ],
    "C_Cpp.default.intelliSenseMode": "gcc-arm64",
    "[cpp]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-vscode.cpptools"
    },
    "editor.renderWhitespace": "all",
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngineFallback": "enabled",
    "C_Cpp.autocompleteAddParentheses": true,
    "[c]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-vscode.cpptools"
    },
    "[python]": {
        "editor.formatOnType": true
    },
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,


}
```

I'm using C++. The problem occurs when i include the headers of interest. Without headers, using these settings I correctly see suggestions for completion (also for local variables), while as soon as I include an header, (e.g. `include <iostream>`), local variables are not suggested any more (I see only suggestions for functions, global variables and const local variables ).

I tries modifying the settings.json file (without any success)

Edit 1:
I'm using C++. The problem occurs when i include the headers of interest. Without heasers, using these settings I correctly see suggestions for completion (also for local variables), while as soon as I include an header, (e.g. "include ), local variables are not suggested any more (I see only suggestions for functions, global variables and const local variables ).

I have enabled the following C/C++ extensions:

C/C++ v1.19.4

C/C++ Extension Pack v1.3.0

C/C++ Themes v2.0.0

Here is a basic test to reproduce my problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int test = 0;

void myFunc()
{
    printf("aaa\n");
}

void main()
{
    int check = 10;
    // Autocompletion does not suggest check with #include <stdio.h>
    // but it suggests it by commenting #include <stdio.h>
    int autocomplete = che...
    
    // myFunc and test are correctly suggested both with and without #include <stdio.h>
}
```

Comment: Which language are you having problems with? Each language has its own extension(s), so the issue could easily be language-specific. It'd also help to give an example, like show some code, put the cursor somewhere, and say what suggestions you'd expect. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] for more tips. Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: There's an existing question about downgrading: [How to downgrade vscode](/q/49346733/4518341). (I just googled "downgrade VS Code" to find that. Please start with your own research in the future.)

Comment: @wjandrea : I'm using C++. The problem occurs when i include the headers of interest. Without heasers, using these settings I correctly see suggestions for completion (also for local variables), while as soon as I include an header, (e.g. "include <iostream>), local variables are not suggested any more (I see only suggestions for functions, global variables and const local variables ).

Comment: Please [edit] to add that. I added the language tag for you :)

Comment: what c++ extensions are you using? please show their extension IDs and version numbers. check also how far back this problem reproduces with them. you can [rollback extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42626065/11107541). please also add code for a [mre], showing in comments in the code where to trigger completion.

Comment: This is the ugly downside to relying on modern IDEs, with these kinds of programming aids and assistants. When they work, they're great! When they break you become a fish out of water. Helpless. Don't know what to do!! Greybeards who learned coding the old fashion way: with a plain text editor, a compiler, and their own brains, as assistants, never have the need to ask this kind of a question.

Comment: @starball : I edited the question with enabled extensions and a basic code to reproduce my error. Thanks for your support.

Comment: what if you use actual absolute paths instead using the `~` for home directory? I also suggested to try rolling back your C/C++ extension... have you tried that yet?

Comment: @starball : Thanks for your suggestions. I tried using the absolute path and nothing changes. As for the extensions that is an interesting point (I said my problem was related to the VS code update, but it could actually be updates of the extensions causing the problem). Sorry for my dumb question ... but how do I roll back an extension to a previous version in VS code?

Comment: click the link in "rollback extensions" in my comment...

Comment: @starball: Thanks. I reverted the  C/C++ extension from v1.19.4 to v1.18.5 and now everything works fine. You are my hero :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce this issue, but according to the asker, it went away for them when they downgraded their cpptools extension from v1.19.4 to v1.18.5, so if you're having this issue, you could use that as a temporary workaround. It might be some kind of bug, so I'd suggest [checking if there's an issue ticket about it already](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues), and if not, raising one.